# C# - How to create fixed size SortedList?

Tags: c#, collections, sortedlist

I only found that SortedList contains IsFixedSize property but I can't find answer to that simple question anywhere.

Comment: Start here: [ask]

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35892291/how-to-implement-a-limited-sorted-list-correctly

Comment: Hi. Can you explain why you need to create a fixed size sortedlist? Perhaps if you explain why you need to do that we can suggest alternative solutions that might accomplish your endgoal.

Comment: fixed size->array

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I need it for equipment in my game, inventory has limited capacity. I know that I can check Count property but I'm just wondering if there is built-in way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This property is something inherited from `IDictionary`, since `SortedList` implements it. This property *will always* return `false` for the default implementation of `SortedList` ([as stated in the msdn documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedlist-2.system-collections-idictionary-isfixedsize?view=netframework-4.7.2)), simply because the default implementation is not fixed size.

Fixed size means that the collection disallows any `Add` or `Remove` type operations (anything that would change the underlying collection, not only the contained elements) after it's constructed **via a wrapper** (again, [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedlist-2.system-collections-idictionary-isfixedsize?view=netframework-4.7.2)). So if you want a `SortedList` of fixed size, you should create your own wrapper, something like

```
public class SortedListFixed<TKey, TValue> : SortedList<TKey, TValue>
{
    private SortedList<TKey, TValue> _list;

    public bool IsFixedSize => true;

    /** ctors **/

    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value) => 
        throw InvalidOperationException("This collection is fixed size");

    public bool Remove (TKey key) =>
        throw InvalidOperationException("This collection is fixed size");

    /** etc. for all inherited size-modifying methods **/
}
```

Two ctors would come in handy, one that takes a capacity, creates the underlying `_list` with that capacity, and a wrapping ctor taking an existing `SortedList` as a parameter. You could also combine the latter with a neat extension method like this:

```
public static class SortedListExtensions
{
    public static SortedListFixed<TKey, TValue> ToFixedSize<TKey, TValue>(
        this SortedList<TKey, TValue> list) => new SortedListFixed<TKey, TValue>(list);

}
```

Note that it's more a guideline than a whole implementation.

Comment: I'm guessing the same thing goes for `TrimToSize`?

Comment: @Tom `TrimToSize` would also fall under "size-modyfing methods".